# Tomcat 7 Restricted (ContainerServlet) error

Tags: java, tomcat, httpclient

I have been stuck on this one for a while.  I am trying to access the ContainerServlet I implemented using HttpClient with Tomcat 7.  I keep getting the error message "Restricted(ContainerServlet)".  I have added Basic Authentication and tried to set it up just like the built in Host-Manager application with no luck.

My HostManagerServlet starts with:

```
public class HostManagerServlet
extends HttpServlet implements ContainerServlet {...
```

My web.xml contains:

```
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>virtualHostCreator</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.eatmyfish.servlets.HostManagerServlet</servlet-class>
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>virtualHostCreator</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/virtualhostcreator/*</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>HostManager commands</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/virtualhostcreator/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
           <!-- NOTE:  This role is not present in the default users file -->
           <role-name>admin-script</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
      </security-constraint>
      <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
          <web-resource-name>HTMLHostManager commands</web-resource-name>
          <url-pattern>/virtualhostcreator/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
           <!-- NOTE:  This role is not present in the default users file -->
           <role-name>admin-gui</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
      </security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to log in to the Host Manager Application HTML
      interface
    </description>
    <role-name>admin-gui</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <description>
      The role that is required to log in to the Host Manager Application text
      interface
    </description>
    <role-name>admin-script</role-name>
  </security-role>
```

My tomcat-users.xml contains:

```
.
.
.
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,admin-gui,admin-script,manager-gui"/>
.
.
.
```

The code that makes the HttpClient call (I've tried a few different approaches):

Approach One -

```
String url = environment.getProperty("baseurl");
        url += "virtualhostcreator/createVirualHost?name="+group.getGroupName();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader(BasicScheme.authenticate(
                 new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat", "tomcat"),
                 "UTF-8", false));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Approach Two -

```
String url = environment.getProperty("baseurl");
        url += "virtualhostcreator/createVirualHost?name="+group.getGroupName();
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope("localhost", 8080),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("tomcat", "tomcat"));
        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local
        // auth cache
        HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080, "http");
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(targetHost, basicAuth);

        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        BasicHttpContext localcontext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localcontext.setAttribute("http.auth.auth-cache", authCache);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(targetHost, httpget,localcontext);
```

The error's stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet virtualHostCreator
java.lang.SecurityException: Restricted (ContainerServlet) class com.eatmyfish.servlets.HostManagerServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.checkAccess(DefaultInstanceManager.java:536)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?  I cannot get past the Restricted(ContainerServlet) error.

Comment: Dean - when you ask a question like this, you should include the stacktrace that reports the error.  If nothing else, it will make it easier for other people with the same problem to find your question / answer.

Comment: I edited my question to include the stack trace per your request.

Comment: @Dean,  what did you write in `getWrapper()` and `setWrapper()` methods

Comment: @Kainix, it has been so long I'm not sure I follow.  What getWrapper() and setWrapper() methods?  I might have this code in source control somewhere I can go look; but I am not sure I did have getWrapper and setWrapper methods.  Why do you think I did?

Comment: @Dean, I asked coz when you implement ContainerServlet you're suppose to override these two methods that's why. Nevertheless I checked into `tomcat 8.0.33` source code and saw how they've done it,but still would like to know what you did.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had a similar problem in Tomcat 7 and was able to work around it by editing the top-level element in `./conf/context.xml` to look like

```
<Context privileged="true">
```

What I can't figure out is how Tomcat's own manager servlets are able to load without this configuration. Anybody have any clues?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.  I needed to set privileged=true in the context of the host inside server.xml